# Is it possible to execute stdout with cscript?

Tags: curl, vbscript, pipe, wsh

I'm trying to execute code from a remote repository directly on the command line with a single command. I'm using CodePile (https://www.codepile.net) which allows raw file access to code snippets. For VBScript files, right now I can do the following:

```
curl -s http://raw.codepile.net/pile/AL9bowz9.vbs > localScript.vbs
cscript localScript.vbs
del localScript.vbs
```

As a way of running the remote code once and not leaving it on my PC. I was hoping I could do:

```
curl -s http://raw.codepile.net/pile/AL9bowz9.vbs | cscript
```

But that doesn't work. I get an error "Failed writing body". I can pipe the curl stdout to something like "| print" and see the contents of the remote file printed in the console.

Is there a way to do this in Windows? I've seen examples showing the syntax:

```
cscript <(curl -s http://raw.codepile.net/pile/AL9bowz9.vbs)
```

But that doesn't seem to work (the system cannot find the file specified)

Also, the pipe syntax I'd like to use does work with other languages (like Python for instance):

```
curl -s http://raw.codepile.net/pile/NJ4QBoY8.py | python
```

Does print "Hello World" to the console.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: While what @ekkehard-horner says is true, there is no reason why you can't using VBScript build a script that will take this and execute it in a one line command something like `cscript LocalScript.vbs "http://raw.codepile.net/pile/AL9bowz9.vbs"` that will use something like `WshShell.Exec("cmd /c " &  strCommand  & " 2>&1")` where `strCommand` is pre-built `curl -s http://raw.codepile.net/pile/NJ4QBoY8.py` string to force execution then use `StdOut` to read the output and execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. (padding)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by (padding)?

Comment: This site won't take a plain "No" for an answer. It insists on a minimal number of characters for an answer.

Comment: LOL...ok, well I guess I'll just accept it and move on. Thanks.